# DNS resolve very slow on php

Tags: php, linux, curl, dns, centos6

i am trying to fetch some external data on my PHP site, but having trouble with DNS resolving. When i use curl i get namelookup_time of about 8 seconds. Also tried file_get_contents with same lousy performance.
Even gethostbyname takes about 8 seconds to resolve.

I am running php on apache web server, running on CentOS 6.6.
My resolv.conf is using google DNS as nameserver, and I don't have any delay when i use dig, hosts, ping or any other DNS related Linux command. Also, if I do curl directly from Linux (or wget), I dont get any delay.

My question is are there any php or apache related dns configuration because i get slow DNS resolve only when using php code, and not when running any linux DNS related command.

UPDATE:

I have made small php script:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true); 

gethostbyname("google.com");

$end = (microtime(true) - $start);
echo "elapsed time: $end";
?>
```

to get time of resolve, and when i run it on apache i get

```
elapsed time: 8.0323350429535
```

If i run using php from command line i get

```
elapsed time: 0.025190830230713
```

so it must be apache related issue.

Comment: Please run the php file in terminal, or just a quick test, and update the question with the results. It might have something to with `apache`

Comment: Updated with quick test, and it works properly when running php from command line. So it must be some apache related problem.

Comment: try to shutdown apache, wait for all processes to close, start it up again

Comment: see the comments from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10009449/5043552, maybe they help

Comment: Thanks Alex. Stop/Start of apache solved it.

Comment: Since I don't know what caused it, feel free to answer the question yourself and accept the answer :)